# Querying S3 inventory details in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have S3 inventory details in S3 bucket and I am querying it through Athena.

My first two columns are shown below:

```
bucket                  key
bke-p0d-bke-lca-data    dl/xxxxxx/plant/archive/01-01-2019/1546300856.json
bke-pod-bke-lca-data    dl/xxxx/plant/archive/01-01-2019/1546300856.json
bke-pod-bke-lca-data    dl/xxx/plant/archive/01-01-2019/1546300856.json
```

I need them to split the key information to below:

```
bucket                  Categ   Type    Date        File
bke-pod-bke-lca-data    xxxxxx  archive 01/01/2019  1546300856.json
bke-pod-bke-lca-data    xxxx    working 01/01/2019  1546300856.json
bke-pod-bke-lca-data    xxx     archive 01/01/2019  1546300856.json
```

I tried `substr` it didnt work.

How I do split based on `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [6.8. String Functions and Operators — Presto 0.172 Documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html) has:

> `split_part(string, delimiter, index)`
>   Splits `string` on `delimiter` and returns the field `index`. Field indexes start with `1`. If the index is larger than than the number of fields, then null is returned.

So, you should be able to use something like:

```
SELECT
  bucket,
  split_part(key, '/', 2) as category,
  split_part(key, '/', 4) as type,
  split_part(key, '/', 5) as date,
  split_part(key, '/', 6) as file
```